# How can I batch with ImageMagick command?

Tags: macos, imagemagick

I'm doing

```
convert dead0000.bmp -alpha on -fill none -draw 'color 0,0 replace' dead0000.png
```

but I have a few thousand files. Is there any way to just do the whole directory at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `for` loop in Bash, macOS' default shell, would suffice:

```
for f in *.bmp; do convert "$f" -alpha on -fill none -draw 'color 0,0 replace' "${f%%.bmp}.png"; done
```

It uses [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to replace the file extension for the output file. Here:

- `"$f"` is the original input filename
- `"${f}"` is the same, just a different way of accessing the variable
- `"${f%%.bmp}.png"` uses string replacement – `f%%.bmp` means, delete the longest match of `.bmp` from the back of `$f`.

Comment: What is `0,0` ?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei I don't know; it was part of the OP's command. You should ask him. It'd be great if you could explain why you downvoted the post.

Comment: But if you look [at the documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#specifics), it says: “In this coordinate system 0,0 is the center of the top-left pixel”.

Comment: I downvoted it because it doesn't explain the command at all. Since not all people have the exact same question, they need to adapt the answers. Also, where is the color that needs to be replaced in that command?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei The question is about how to batch-run a particular command. In this case it doesn't matter if it's an ImageMagick command or if some other tool is used. The job of an answer shouldn't be to explain what a command does, when it is already given in the question, and that question is not about the actual functionality of the command. I do realize sometimes people find questions related to their problems, but with a different focus. This is one such question. If you have a problem understanding the command, please read the documentation and ask a new question instead.

Comment: Yes, I saw afterward. I don't usually read the questions, and I'm curious if I'm the only one. The thing is that I searched how to remove a color with imagemagick, not how to batch run a command, hence my mistake. I edited the answer to remove my downvote.

Comment: Sure, I understand. I added a few more explanations on how string manipulation works in case that helps others.

Comment: Great, upvoted, sorry again!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this. mogrify is a powerful scripting tool for imagemagick 
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php (and *.bmp)

Comment: Please add more than just a link as an answer. While it might be helpful, we would like the actual answer *here*, on Super User. Especially if the OP is asking for a command, you should be able to give some solution. Thanks